# Cypress run test for each item returned from a promise

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress code where I want to get list of all product of certain type and certain country and run a test on each single one of them.

My code:

```
const markets = [...];
const types = [...];
const element = '...';
const getAsin = async (market, type) => { Cypress.$.ajax .... }

describe('My tests', () => {
    markets.forEach(market => {
        types.forEach(type => {
            getproduct(market, type).then(res => {
                const products = res.body.products;
                products.forEach(productRec => {
                    cy.log();
                    it('testing: ' + market, () => {
                        const productUrl = getUrl(...);

                        cy.visit(productUrl);

                        // Check that element exists
                        cy.get('#' + element).should("exist");
                    });
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                cy.log(`err: ${err}`);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Unfortunately Cypress is telling me "No tests found."

[image: pic]

I have the `it` definition, so I assume it is linked to the promise call. I could define `it` above the Promise call and it would work, but then I have all products in one tests and if just one fails, the whole test fails and the rest of the list is not executed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add the error screenshot to the question?

Comment: Added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getproduct(market, type)` is asynchronous.

Cypress scans the spec file *synchronously* for `it()` blocks, but since there's no immediate response to `getProduct()` it does not see any.

I would say you can't do the products fetch inside the spec file, but you could do it in `setupNodeEvents` (assuming Cypress v 10+) using the `before:run` hook

Install `node-fetch` and `fs-extra`.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

const markets = [...];
const types = [...];

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const getproduct = (market, type) => fetch(...);  // no async here

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:run', async (details) => {       

        const fs = require('fs-extra');           // to write fixture
        const marketProducts = {}
        try {
          markets.forEach(market => {
            marketProducts[market] = {}
            types.forEach(async (type) => {       // async here
              const products = await getproduct(market, type).then(res => res.body.products);
              marketProducts[market][type] = products
            }
          }
          fs.writeJson('./cypress/fixtures/marketProducts.json', marketProducts)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error:', error)
        }
      })
    }),

    experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true,  // required to use the before:run hook
  }
})
```

**Test**

```js
const marketProducts = require('../fixtures/marketProducts.json')

describe('My tests', () => {
  markets.forEach(market => {
    types.forEach(type => {
      const products = marketProducts[market][type];
      products.forEach(productRec => {

        it('testing: ' + market, () => {
         ...
```

Comment: Does it have to be in `cypress.config.js` or can it be in any js file?

Comment: It can be any js file, but if it's external to the Cypress ecosystem you need to call it before starting up Cypress itself. For example, a Node script that runs before `npx cypress open` - but be careful of the `async/await` that needs to finish before Cypress runner starts.

Comment: Your line `const products = await getproduct(market, type).then(res => res.body.products);` gives a syntax error when starting Cypress: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules".

Comment: You will need to add the async keyword here `on('before:run', async (details) => {`

Comment: I do have it there. I followed your code.

Comment: You're right, it's needed on the inner callback `types.forEach(async (type) => {`